# Trigger the opening of a second program when opening another

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

How does one go about adding a trigger to open another program when the first opens. Specifically, I would like to open PeerBlock whenever I run uTorrent, but I can see this being very useful for other tasks as well.

I've tried using Task Scheduler, but cannot find a trigger that corresponds to uTorrent (or a non-Windows-based trigger for that matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be to replace the shortcut to your application with a shortcut to a batch file that opens the application and the 2<sup>nd</sup> application.

Something like this:

```
@echo off
start "main title" "C:\program files\main application\main application.exe"
start "other title" "C:\program files\other application\other application.exe"
```

(double check the syntax as I'm a little rusty)

Answer (score 0):

**Specifically for uTorrent....**

In the Preferences dialog box of uTorrent, open Advanced > Run Program. There you can write an executable's address to run when the state of a torrent changes. So you can start another program when a torrent starts. It has a specific style like thsi: IF %S==1 (means if state is started). You can find description of commands and state info on the same window.