# osx: launch a program when another program opens

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, launcher, application-launch

I would like a method for starting a program when another program starts. Specifically, I’d like a to open a MS Word document and have my citation manager open simultaneously (EndNote supports this function within MS Word preferences, but I recently switched citation managers).

I’d like to be able to open any existing Word document on my drive and trigger the second program. [The same question](https://superuser.com/questions/507172/launch-a-program-when-another-program-opens?rq=1) was recently answered for the windows 7 environment.

Comment: This is a great question, I would also like to know how to close one program when another closes. Can this be done the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try saving a property list like this as `~/Libary/LaunchAgents/test.plist` and loading it with `launchctl load ~/Libary/LaunchAgents/test.plist`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>osascript</string>
    <string>-e</string>
    <string>tell application "System Events"
    set p to name of processes
    if p contains "TextEdit" and p does not contain "Mail"
    do shell script "open -gja Mail"
    end
    end</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`open -j` (`--hide`) was added in 10.8. `open -jg` sometimes opens a new visible window if an application is running but has no open windows.

If StartInterval is 9 seconds or less, the program just gets throttled.

```
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[128]: (test) Throttling respawn: Will start in 7 seconds
```

Comment: Can we close either application when the other closes in the same method?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code. I managed to extend it a bit to also close the launched process if the original watched process isn't running anymore. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>TextEditWatcher</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>osascript</string>
    <string>-e</string>
    <string>tell application "System Events"
        set p to name of processes
        if p contains "TextEdit" and p does not contain "Mail" then
            do shell script "open -gja Mail"
        end if
        if p does not contain "TextEdit" and p contains "Mail" then
            tell application "Mail" to quit
        end if
        end tell</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>30</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

On my System (10.9.4), a StartInterval of 10 was already too much and as timing isn't crucial in my case, I chose 30 seconds. But 15 or 20 should be fine too. Installation and testing like mentioned in Lri's answer.